# Парсер аргументов

Tags: python

```
import sys


try:
    name = int(sys.argv)
    for i in range(len(name)):
        print(sys.argv[i + 1])
except BaseException:
    print("no args")
```

Вот мой код.
Вот задание: Напишите скрипт, который принимает любое кол-во параметров через произвольное количество пробелов в качестве аргументов и выводит их в той же последовательности на экран, каждый на отдельной строке.
В случае отсутствия параметров скрипт должен выводить «no args».
Не понимаю, как сделать так что бы он считал все аргументы,а не только первый.
Вот пример:
Ввод:python3 solution.py 5 string 1
Вывод:

5

string

1

Comment: Вообще с вашим кодом должна выходить ошибка `TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()`

Comment: Зачем такой сложный код, это же делается элементарно `for x in sys.argv[1:]: print(x)`

Comment: А, ну и проверка через `if len(sys.argv) > 1`

Comment: Перехватывайте максимально узкий класс исключения. Уж точно не нужно ловить BaseException, когда нужно было перехватить всего лишь IndexError. BaseException у вас перехватит вообще все, даже прерывание программы `sys.exit()`, а сообщение будет выведено, как будто не переданы аргументы.